# How can I read multiple CSV files and merge them in single dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 4 CSV files with different columns. Some CSV have same column name as well. The details of the csv are:

```
capstone_customers.csv: [customer_id, customer_type, repeat_customer]

capstone_invoices.csv: [invoice_id,product_id,  customer_id, days_until_shipped,  product_line, total]

capstone_recent_customers.csv: [customer_id, customer_type]

capstone_recent_invoices.csv: [invoice_id,product_id,  customer_id, days_until_shipped,  product_line, total]
```

My code is:

```py
df1 = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',').csv("capstone_customers.csv")
    df2 = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',').csv("capstone_invoices.csv")
    df3 = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',').csv("capstone_recent_customers.csv")
    df4 = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',').csv("capstone_recent_invoices.csv")


    from functools import reduce
    def unite_dfs(df1, df2):
      return df2.union(df1)
    
    list_of_dfs = [df1, df2,df3,df4]
    united_df = reduce(unite_dfs, list_of_dfs)
```

but I got the error:

> Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 6 columns and the second table has 3 columns;;\n'Union\n:- Relation[invoice_id#234,product_id#235,customer_id#236,days_until_shipped#237,product_line#238,total#239] csv\n+- Relation[customer_id#218,customer_type#219,repeat_customer#220] csv\n

How can I merge in a single data frame and remove same column names using PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read multiple files in shark you can make list of all files you want and read them at once, you don't have to read them in order.

Here is an example of code you can use:

```py
path = ['file.cvs','file.cvs']
 
df = spark.read.options(header=True).csv(path)
df.show()
```

Comment: but it not add customer_type, repeat_customer column in df 
 df= [ invoice_id, product_id , customer_id, days_until_shipped,  product_line: string ,total]
 Why customer type and repeat customer not add in final df?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can provide list of files or path to files to read, instead of reading one by one. And don't forget about `mergeSchema` option:

```
files = [
   "capstone_customers.csv",
   "capstone_invoices.csv",
   "capstone_recent_customers.csv",
   "capstone_recent_invoices.csv"
]
df = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',', mergeSchema='True').csv(files)

# or
df = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',header='True',delimiter=',',mergeSchema='True').csv('/path/to/files/')
```

Comment: The customer_type, repeat_customer  column is not include  in df 
 df= [ invoice_id, product_id , customer_id, days_until_shipped,  product_line: string ,total]